# Publishing django views with already existing db tables

Tags: python, django

I have experience programming in python, but am new to Django. I recently went through the tutorial and eveything made sense, however I am wondering if I can create views from DB tables that already exists without having to create models. Or, if this isn't possible is there a way to create models to generate an ORM with a DB table that already exists?

Basically I have Aggregate metrics in data warehouse tables that I would like to publish to a web page in real time. Is Django the right tool for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`./manage.py inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) to create models from an existing database.